# eclipse kepler, nodeclipse, coffeesctipt and ctrl+/ comments

Tags: coffeescript, comments, eclipse-kepler, nodeclipse

i am trying to use Eclipse's nodeclipse plugin to edit coffeescript files. the problem is, when i try to comment a line using ctrl+/, it comments the like with // (java style comment) instead on # (coffeesctipt style comments). anyone knows a solution to that? can i change the comment marker for a specific file type?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any way to change the behaviour of ctrl+/ to fit coffeesctipt (# instead of //) in Enide bundle. There is no specific page for CoffeeScript editor settings, or even a way to activate it, for that matter (to the attention of the Enide developers).

While Enide was the only result for searching for CoffeeScript on the Eclipse Marketplace (if you have the marketplace - it is the left-most icon on the bottom left, with the Eclipse logo), I switched to the Yoxos Marketplace and found CoffeeScript-Editor (yes, as simple as that). after installing, I had an option to open .coffeescript files using a CoffeeScript editor, which comments the right way.

Comment: Nodeclipse CoffeeScript project is at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/coffeescript-eclipse

@Ehud Please update your answer to give more links, and more detailed.

For discussion please create issue at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/coffeescript-eclipse/issues